# Count the new message received?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a chat application. When a user sends a message, the receiver needs to be notified the number of message sent. The PHP fetches the result form MySQL and using `$.get` to get the message using Ajax.

```
setInterval(function(){
            $.get("get.php",function(msgs){
                $("#chats").html(msgs);                 
            });
        },1000);
```

I use `setInterval()` to check the messages every 3 seconds. 
I have the database like this:

```
user
message
status
```

The default value of `status` is `0`, when the user click the message, `status` is updated to `1`. This update happens with Ajax request.
How can i check a new message has arrived and show the the count of new message received?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question requires a complex for a solution. I guess you are using a DataBase to store those messages, right? What about set those new messagem as unread and then count and notify this number? Please, provde more information. That's one of idea..

Comment: @bcesars Question updated!

Comment: What does get.php return?  HTML, JSON, etc?  If you have it return JSON then you can simply use javascript to count and display the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Make new messages with some class like the incoming messages with

```
<span class="new-message">Text</span>
```

Now you can count the number of messages.

```
alert($(".new-message").length);
```

Try this.